# How to return after rendering Jade template in Express.JS?

Tags: node.js, express

Please consider the simple express.js route:

```
app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
   if(condition1) {
      res.render("foo", {
          title : "Test"
      });
   }

   console.log("HERE");

   if(condition2) {
      res.render("bar", {
          title : "Test2"
      });
   }
});
```

Now, in this contrived example, sometimes condition1 will be true, and other times, condition2. However, in the case that condition1 is true, the control passes through and prints out the console.log line and then fails when it hits the other render with:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

It's like the response needs to be ended or something, but I've tried that, to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use `return res.render()`.

It's strange when you say it doesn't work, because return really should stop the rest of the function from executing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an `else`, so that only one code path leads to a res. `res.send` already ends a response, but you are trying to send another response with another `res.render`

Simple change the second if to an `else if`, and move around the code to allow for this, ie move the console.log above all the conditionals.

Or, I believe you can just place a `return` statement after the `res.render`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response Rafal. The if-else is definitely an option, but I was trying to avoid it if possible (in this contrived example, it would be fine). In addition, I have tried placing a return after the render to no avail. Also, I have tried returning the actual render itself (i.e., return res.render()), but that didn't seem to work either.